# What does this command do? sed '/ab/bc/g'

Tags: sed

`sed` command with only `g`:
I know what `sed 's/ab/bc/g'` does, but without the `s`, I don't what it would do. It doesn't seem to work in the terminal:

```bash
$ sed '/^c/d/g' word.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: extra characters after command
```

Comment: The fact that it gives an error and nothing else tells you all that you need to know.

Comment: That looks like a typo that is giving you an error.

Comment: Which command are you asking about, `sed '/ab/bc/g'` ("jump to the non-existent label `c/g` whenever `ab` matches") or `sed '/^c/d/g'` (an invalid `d` command with extra characters at the end, triggered by matching `c` at the start of a line)?

Comment: ok yeah this is a typo.  In my homework I accidentally erased the "s" inside the command, so I was confused why this would even be a question mb. The original question had the "s".

Answer (score 0):

Sed can be limited to a subset of lines in a file by adding a search condition to the command. The search condition is of the form `/search/`. Thus if you omit the `s` from `-e 's/^c/d/g'`, it becomes another command altogether: `-e '/^c/ d'`.

The `d` command deletes the line and does not take any options, which is why you get the "extra characters after command" error.

Without the extra `/g`, this command will delete every line that starts with 'c':

```
   $ cat t
   c is what we want
   d is not
   this file has 3 lines.
   $ sed -e 's/^c/d/g' t
   d is what we want
   d is not
   this file has 3 lines.
   $ sed -e '/^c/d' t
   d is not
   this file has 3 lines.
```